# Не работает exe переведенный из py

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

Нужно код ниже перевести в exe файл. Использовал pyinstaller, все скомпилировалось, но при запуске exe файла консоль появляется на миллисекунду и сразу исчезает. Текса в ней нет, она пустая.
В коде есть строчки скрывающие консоль, пробовал их комментировать и все перекомпилировать, но проблема осталась. Может можно сделать exe файл по другому?
На самом деле можно и я даже это делал с этим кодом, но я не помню, что именно использовал. Там был сайт с белым фоном, с подробной инструкцией. Также в ней говорилось создать отдельный setup.py. Может кто-нибудь помнит, что за сайт?
У меня даже есть билд той версии, может там можно где-нибудь узнать, с помощью чего он создавался?

**UPD:**
При запуске exe файла через консоль пишет

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telethon'
[16492] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

```
import random
from time import sleep
import win32gui
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con
from telethon import TelegramClient


def file_to_string_array(filename):
    result = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            result.append(i.replace('\n', ''))
    return result


def split_input(array):
    result = []
    while True:
        try:
            result.append([array[0], array[1], array[2]])
            array.pop(0)
            array.pop(0)
            array.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            break
    return result


def first_run_to_false():
    with open('telegram_input.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines[0] = 'False\n'
    with open('telegram_input.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)


async def main():
    await client.send_message(chat, text)
    sleep(2)
    async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
        if 0 < message.button_count < 11:
            await message.click(random.randint(0, message.button_count - 1))
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = file_to_string_array('telegram_input.txt')
    first_run = data[0]
    users = split_input(data[1:])
    chat = '@aeawed'
    text = 'Hello'

    for user in users:
        client = TelegramClient(user[2], int(user[0]), user[1])
        with client:
            if first_run == 'False':
                the_program_to_hide = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
                win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide, win32con.SW_HIDE)
            client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
            # if first_run == 'False':
            #     win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide, win32con.SW_SHOW)

    if first_run == 'True':
        first_run_to_false()
```

Comment: Нашел, это py2exe https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial. Отпишу, получилось или нет

Comment: Нет, проблема осталась

Comment: Проблемы нет, если запускать код в компиляторе, до перевода из .py в .exe

Comment: Может проблема в импортах? Нужен requirements.txt?

Comment: Код для работы использует 2 файла, но проблема не в них, так как я их поместил и в проект и в билд (то есть они всегда находятся программой)

Comment: Питон версии 3.9, может в этом проблема?

Comment: Попробовал написать `pip install telethon` и похоже получилось

Comment: Возможно, вы не импортировали в ваш .exe-файл использованные библиотеки. В параметрах найдите --hidden-import и по-очереди добавьте туда все использованные библиотеки, даже если они по умолчанию установлены в python. Также рекомендую проверить, использует ли программа дополнительные файлы. Если да - то компилируйте всю папку. Если вы используете конкретную часть библиотеки/название при pip install и import, то укажите название из импорта в --collect-submodules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что я для тестов постоянно копировал папку с проектом, чтобы поставить pyinstaller, но видимо при копировании папки не копируются импорты. Помогло `pip install telethon` в новой скопированной папке.
Также `the_program_to_hide = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide, win32con.SW_HIDE)` тут не совсем подходит. Консоль, во-первых, появится в самом начале все равно, так как перед этими строчками происходят вычисления с незакрытой консолью. Во-вторых, эти строки находятся в цикле. Первый раз они спрячут консоль, а все последующие разы - активные окна, которые потом можно будет закрыть только через Диспетчер задач.